# where to find reference for video html element since MDN is missing a lot

Tags: html, video

I found this reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video for the video element and it is missing some of the DOM api like video.volume, which is covered by W3. Can someone help with either finding this information on MDN, since that is supposedly the definitive source for all things web or another one-stop shop that I can use after finding that maybe MDN is not as complete as I had thought? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`volume`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume) is defined on the [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/) interface that [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) inherits from.

It is not an attribute on the [`<video>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

Also, W3C left the specification of HTML to the WHATWG organization, only a few specs from W3C will extend these interfaces, so you need to check all these various specs.
But MDN is still the best up-to-date resource to see them all in one place.